# Move from Curl to Aria2?

Tags: php

We have a crawling engine that uses curl and caters to about 400,000 ppl  / month. Although curl supports concurrent downloads, it does not support bandwidth limiting ( only in php 5.4.0 ) which is why my boss wants me to move to aria2. He also says Aria2 is faster ( which seems to be true to me as well )

[Aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) would require a large amounts of changes to the system. Right now we have crawling system which does not crawl in a conconrrent manner.

Would moving to aria2 be a good decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running quiet a few test we found aria and curl/php/apache are running at almost the same speed. We decided to stick to curl as it has a php library libcurl. We are not sure about bandwidth limiting but are working on it. Changing our current code to crawl multiple pages simultaneously was not such a big hassle as of curl. Although there have been some things we need to work around e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878546/curl-multi-crawling-issues

Answer (score 2):

1. **Bandwidth limiting** is supported by PHP Ext cURL.
   The settings you are looking for is:
   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 10240);`
2. **aria2c** is faster than cURL on mirrored downloads, because it allows **fetching parts from multiple sources in parallel and combines them**. this is not supported by cURL, afaik. rebuilding this feature on PHP side is possible, but the handling is slower than with aria2c.